# through admin or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

Am using activeadmin, and doing some customizations, where I am dealing with few existing application controllers/views, where I want to know that, say inside a view whether I came from admin portal?

So I have a partial that I am using in my application a couple of ways, plus now I am also using it from activeadmin, and hence I want to know in that partial, whether this came from app or activeadmin, so in short whether url contains `<host>/admin` or not.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only admin users can reach the partial via the ActiveAdmin UI, you can query for the user being an admin. If you use Devise for authentication it would look like:

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
  <%= render "your_only_admin_content %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

In case you want to differentiate when an admin browses the regular site or through active admin you may want to use nested layouts. To do that you will have to use two layouts - one for the admin and one for the regular site browsing. Most chance you already are since you said only the partial is shared between the two cases. 
To use nested layouts, put the following inside the partial:

```
<%= yield(:admin_user) if content_for?(:admin_user) %>
```

and in the layout that is used by admin:

```
<% content_for :admin_user do %>
  <%= render "your_only_admin_content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `admin_signed_in` can be true even if admin user is browsing non-admin stuff in my case, I am not following `AdminUser` as suggested by activeadmin to be device powered. I had to support my existing user base and existing admins(user.admin(boolean))